# Count elements lower than a given value in a std::set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I need to find how many elements are lower than a given one in a `std::set`.

I thought the right function to use was `std::lower_bound` which returns an iterator to the first element which is greater or equal to the given one....so the index of this iterator is what I'm looking for...but I can't find the index from the iterator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> mySet;
    mySet.insert( 1 );
    mySet.insert( 2 );
    mySet.insert( 3 );
    mySet.insert( 4 );

    std::set<int>::const_iterator found = std::lower_bound( mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), 2 );

    if ( found != mySet.end() )
        std::cout << "Value 2 was found at position " << ( found - mySet.begin() ) << std::endl;
else
        std::cout << "Value 2 was not found" << std::endl;
}
```

This does not compile:

```
16:63: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::set<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}' and 'std::set<int>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}')
16:63: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/random.h:34,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/random:49,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62,
                 from 3:
```

Using std::vector instead of std::set works [perfectly](http://cpp.sh/2wgq4).

Looks like operator- is not valid for a `std::set::iterator`. Why?
Then, how can you easily (without calling `std::previous` or `std::next` untill bound is reached...this would not be efficient) find the position of a given iterator in the container? If you can't, then what alterantive can I use to find the index of a given element...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looks like operator- is not valid for a std::set::iterator. Why?

Indeed, an implementation of `std::set::iterator::operator-()` can't exist in constant complexity since the elements are not contiguous in memory.

---

> Then, how can you easily (without calling std::previous or std::next until bound is reached...this would not be efficient) find the position of a given iterator in the container?

You can't, `std::set::iterator` is not a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). See [`std::distance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) documentation:

> **Complexity**
>
> Linear.

---

> If you can't, then what alterantive can I use to find the index of a given element...?

I'd suggest to count your elements without having to compute an iterator distance: [`std::count_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) can help us:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> mySet;
    mySet.insert( 1 );
    mySet.insert( 2 );
    mySet.insert( 3 );
    mySet.insert( 4 );

    const std::size_t lower_than_three = std::count_if(
         std::begin(mySet)
        , std::end(mySet)
        , [](int elem){ return elem < 3; } );
    std::cout << lower_than_three << std::endl;    
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0481e249335fe98)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do a lower bound search is with [`std::set`'s own `lower_bound` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound), which is specially designed to work with this sorted, associative, non-random-access container.

So, instead of this:

```
std::lower_bound( mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), 2 );
```

use this:

```
mySet.lower_bound(2);
```

This is logarithmic in the size of the container, which is much better than [a `std::count_if` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35894348/560648) (which doesn't know about the sortyness of the comparator, and therefore must visit all the nodes and is thus linear).

However, you then must also use `std::distance` from the beginning to the lower bound, which is not only linear but also necessarily "slow" in practice (due to the non-random-access).

[Nathan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35894488/560648) seems optimal given that you do not want to simply find the lower bound, but find its distance from the "start" of the container.

Comment: I never noticed `std::[multi]set` (and map) had their own `lower_bound` :)

Comment: @YSC: Magic! :D

Comment: That's an interesting answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since `std::set::iterator` is a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) we cannot subtract from it unless we use the decrement operator.  What we can do though is just walk the set and count the iterations until we reach a number bigger than what we are looking for.

```
std::set<int> mySet;
// fill values
int counter = 0;
for (auto it = mySet.begin(), *it < some_value && it != mySet.end(); ++it)
{
    if (e < some_value)
        counter++;
}
```

This is a worst `mySet.size()` iterations which is as fast as you can get it when dealing with a BidirectionalIterator.

Also note that [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) does not have O(log N) complexity since we are not using a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).  When using a non-RandomAccessIterator it has linear complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code for this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> mySet;
    mySet.insert( 1 );
    mySet.insert( 2 );
    mySet.insert( 3 );
    mySet.insert( 4 );

    std::set<int>::const_iterator found = std::lower_bound( mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), 2 );
    std::size_t dist = std::distance(found, mySet.end());
    std::cout << "Number of lower bound elements: " << dist << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please forget about `std::lower_bound` with set/map iterators, it is o(n). Use `set.lower_bound` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on all the existing answers - you can always write your own `operator-`.

```
template<class T, class = typename 
    std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
    typename T::iterator_category,
    std::bidirectional_iterator_tag
>::value>::type>
typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type operator-(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return std::distance(b, a);
}
```

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks.